# How should I use MVVM and Dependency Injection when I need to fetch a controller data from two different web services?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, dependency-injection, repository-pattern

I use MVVM design pattern in my swift project. In a view controller I need to get data from two different web services. So I need to create a view model in the controller like below:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

var viewModel: MyViewModel = MyViewModel(repository: NetworkLayer(service1: WebService1(), service2: WebService2()))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         viewModel.getData(catUrl, categoryId: "\(catId)")
    }
}
```

The viewmodel is responsible to fetch data from servers and update the views via controller. I found Repository design pattern and Dependency Injection to solve my problem :

```
class MyViewModel {
    var webService1: WebService1?
    var webService2: WebService2?

    init(repository: NetworkLayer) {
        self.webService1 = repository.service1
        self.webService2 = repository.service2
    }

    func getData(_ url: String, categoryId: String) {
        webService1?.delegate = self
        webService1?.getData(urlCode: url)

        webService2?.delegate = self
        webService2?.getProducts(queryString: "sortby=14&pageno=0&status=2&pagesize=20&category=c\(categoryId)")
    }
}

class NetworkLayer: WebService1Delegate, WebService2Delegate {  
    var webService1: WebService1?
    var webService2: WebService2?

    init(service1: WebService1, service2: WebService2) {
        self.service1 = service1
        self.service2 = service2
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me is my way to handle this situation correct? If not, what is the best way to cope with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest you should probably make use of protocols if you want to properly implement repository pattern. For example, you would create a protocol like this

```
protocol RepositoryProtocol {
    func fetchInformation() -> String
}
```

So your service classes must implement this. So here is an example

```
class MyService: RepositoryProtocol {
    func fetchInformation() -> String {

        return ""
    }
}
```

You should also create a view model protocol as well for safety.

```
protocol ViewModel {
    associatedtype Repo
    init (withRepo repo: Repo)
}
```

So this says, classes that conform to this ViewModel protocol will have some of type defined in the view model and it MUST be injected on the init method. Also benefit, it is no an longer optional object.

So here is an example of the view model

```
struct MyViewModel : ViewModel {
    typealias Repo = RepositoryProtocol

    let repo : RepositoryProtocol
    init(withRepo repo: Repo) {
        self.repo = repo
    }
}
```

So here you can see, your view model must be injected with an object that conforms to a protocol which you define in your view model class. As you can see, typealias has been used to say this object will be of type RepositoryProtocol. You can update the view model protocol so it requires the view model gets initialized with as many services as you need

This is a much better approach to handling repo pattern and dependency injection.